# Shortcut for removing try statement in Resharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring, resharper

I have such code, where try statement has no sense (in my opinion). How can I remove such try statement by Re# by one action? One action means key shortcut or click in some option in Re#.

```
try
{
    obj.Prop = "sth";
    obj.PropInt = 12*94;
}
catch(Exception ex) // catch is empty
{
}
```

Comment: This is no simple refactoring since you change the behaviour of the program in case exceptions are thrown.

Comment: This is a bad practice, but does have the purpose of lazily doing some work that is not critical in the try block, while ignoring exceptions.